# Why aren't these 2 strings equal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Going blind here.. I can't understand why these 2 strings are not equal.. When I `puts` them to the terminal they are both class `string` and when I just compare the output they ARE equal. But somehow in my code they are not.. I can't figure out why.

Here is my Ruby code:

```
def prep_for_duplicate_webhook
  @redis_cart = Redis.new
  cart_stamp_saved = @redis_cart.get("cart_stamp_saved")
  if cart_stamp_saved.nil?
    cart_stamp_saved = {}
    cart_stamp_saved[:token] = cart_params['token']
    cart_stamp_saved[:updated_at] = cart_params['updated_at']
    @redis_cart.set("cart_stamp_saved", cart_stamp_saved.to_json)
  end
  @cart_stamp_incoming = {}
  @cart_stamp_incoming["token"] = cart_params['token']
  @cart_stamp_incoming["updated_at"] = cart_params['updated_at']
end

def duplicate_webhook?
  prep_for_duplicate_webhook
  @cart_stamp_saved = redis_cart.get("cart_stamp_saved")
  cart_stamp_saved == cart_stamp_incoming.to_json
end
```

And then the hash's I'm comparing are these two:

```
cart_stamp_saved = {"token"=>"4a093432ba5c430dd545b16c0e89f187", 
"updated_at"=>"2017-02-17T15:27:22.923Z"}

cart_stamp_incoming= {"token"=>"4a093432ba5c430dd545b16c0e89f187", 
"updated_at"=>"2017-02-17T15:27:22.923Z"}
```

If I just copy and paste the above into a new page, and the do this, the response is `true`

```
pp cart_stamp_saved == cart_stamp_incoming.to_json
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're saying both are strings but you're showing us two hashes...

Comment: Why are you comparing them as strings anyway? This will fail if e.g. the order of the keys changes (which, since JSON mappings are unordered, is entirely possible). You should deserialize them both and compare the resulting hashes.

Comment: Ok, let me try that.. yea I don't want to compare them as strings, but I thought that was the default class when getting from Redis

Comment: Yea I'm still stuck.. tried deserializing with `JSON` and `Marshall` and they both return errors..

Comment: What output do you get with this – `puts "SAVED: #{cart_stamp_saved}\n\nINCOMING: #{cart_stamp_incoming.to_json}"` – above your `cart_stamp_saved == cart_stamp_incoming.to_json` line? Just so we can see exactly what you're comparing.

Comment: Its what I put in the OP.. it looks like this.. `cart_stamp_saved = {"token"=>"4a093432ba5c430dd545b16c0e89f187", 
"updated_at"=>"2017-02-17T15:27:22.923Z"}`

`cart_stamp_incoming= {"token"=>"4a093432ba5c430dd545b16c0e89f187", 
"updated_at"=>"2017-02-17T15:27:22.923Z"}`

Comment: @cart_stamp_saved is an instance variable and cart_stamp_saved is an undefined local variable or defined somewhere else.

Comment: @ToddT I'd like to see _exactly_ what you're comparing on the `cart_stamp_saved == cart_stamp_incoming.to_json` line. Since you're using `to_json` on `cart_stamp_incoming`, it's definitely not `{"token"=>"4a093432ba5c430dd545b16c0e89f187", "updated_at"=>"2017-02-17T15:27:22.923Z"}`, which is a hash.

Comment: "redis_cart" or "@redis_cart" in the second function?